# How to identify the relation between elements in JAXB

Tags: jaxb

Is there intelligent way to identify relation between elements using JAXB.

For example: If element **SMTP** is referred/used in the element **Notification** and element  **Configuration**

```
<element name="SMTP">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
              <element name="fromEmailAddress" type="string"/>
              <element name="hostName" type="string"/>
              <element name="portNumber" type="string"/>
      </sequence>
  </complexType>
 </element> 

<element name="Notification">
       <complexType>
        <sequence>
           <element ref="tns:SMTP"/>
         </sequence>
       </complexType>
 </element>

<element name="Configuration">
       <complexType>
        <sequence>
           <element ref="tns:SMTP"/>
         </sequence>
       </complexType>
 </element>
```

Is there way to identify this relation/dependancy(SMTP with Notification & Configuration) using JAXB(iam using JAXB to generate classes for the above elements present in my XSD).If it is, sample java code will be helpful

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

The Configuration and Notification classes will be generated with an SMTP property:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "smtp"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Configuration")
public class Configuration {

    @XmlElement(name = "SMTP", namespace = "urn:example", required = true)
    protected SMTP smtp;

    public SMTP getSMTP() {
        return smtp;
    }

    public void setSMTP(SMTP value) {
        this.smtp = value;
    }

}
```

If you are looking to make this a bidirectional relationship you can leverage the @XmlInverseReference extension in [EclipseLink JAXB](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) (I'm the tech lead).  For more information see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html

Comment: Iam more looking for a way to identify the relation which exists. For example If i have java function i send a String as element name "SMTP", it should return back telling that "Notification" and "Configuration" are the 2 elements which uses "SMTP". Convential way is do write java program based on my xsd. Where i need to manual check & find this relation and send back. So is there way to identify this in JAXB or any other way?